# How to change responsive style using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I have a responsive style, like this:

```
@media all and (max-width:799px){ 
  .bigFont{ font-size: 28px; }
}

@media all and (min-width:800px){ 
  .bigFont{ font-size: 48px; }
}
```

If using jQuery to change the style like this:

```
$(.bigFont).css("font-size", "30px");
```

It will change the font size in both media.

My question is how to change the bigFont's font-size for one of them using jQuery?

Comment: It doesnt really change it for both media. It just sets this as an inline CSS for the elements for your selector. Since this is inline it reflects at all widths. In your case, you should probably look at using an if condition on window width and then setting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you need to do is to add another class

```
@media all and (max-width:799px){ 
  .bigFont{ font-size: 28px; }
  .bigFont30{ font-size: 30px; }
}

@media all and (min-width:800px){ 
  .bigFont{ font-size: 48px; }
}
```

Jquery

```
$(.bigFont).addClass("bigFont30");
```

This will only change the font size for first media query

Note: This will only work if you know the font you want to set before hand else put a `$(window).width()` check