# Use Javascript or JQuery to insert a responsive CSS rule

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, responsive-design, media-queries

Let's suppose I want to dynamically add CSS rules that are tied to a media condition. For example, something like following:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 500px){
    .someClass: {
        color: blue;
    }
}
```

A logical step would be to use JavaScript to check the validity of the media query and insert the rule if the test passes. Something like following:

```
if(matchMedia(only screen and (min-device-width : 500px))){
    $('.someClass').css('color', 'blue');
}
```

The drawback being that the rule would NOT be responsive. If I change the screen size, the blue color will not change accordingly. I can add a listener to screen size changes but I think it's a bit overkill.

My question is: is there a way to add a *responsive* rule via Javascript or JQuery?

Comment: Check if it helpful to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14068024/how-to-change-responsive-style-using-jquery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to hear about [enquire.js](http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/):

```
enquire.register("screen and (max-width:1000px)", {

    match : function() {},      // REQUIRED
                                // Triggered when the media query transitions 
                                // *from an unmatched state to a matched state*

    unmatch : function() {},    // OPTIONAL
                                // If supplied, triggered when the media query transitions 
                                // *from a matched state to an unmatched state*.

    setup : function() {},      // OPTIONAL
                                // If supplied, a one-time setup function 
                                // triggered when the handler is first registered.                           

    deferSetup : true,          // OPTIONAL, defaults to false
                                // If set to true, defers execution the setup function until
                                // the media query is first matched. Setup is still triggered just once.

    destroy : function() {}     //OPTIONAL
                                // If supplied, triggered when a hander is unregistered (covered later). 
                                // Enables you to provide lifecycle to responsive widgets. 
                                // Put cleanup logic here.

}).listen(); // More on this next
```

[from the docs]

EDIT: if you want to add a pure CSS rule via js [without relying on a listener], I think it is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can render dynamic css using responsive.js library. It helps you to define dinamically your responsive rules that will be rendered on client side as native css. It use a fluent interface programming style and it works also if media queries arent supported (dynamically render current valid rules).

For example you can define width property as :

```
r$.breakpoints(320,767,1280);
r$.set('width','px').values(100,300,1500).linearInt().applyTo('.class');
```

More information, download and examples at :

http://www.responsivejs.com